# React - Rendering and iterating components

Tags: reactjs, parse-platform

I'm iterating array of objects using ES6 map function and updating it to `<li>` list items. Log is printing correctly. But the list items is not showing up in UI.

**Code:**

```
renderListItems() {
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Test");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length);
            return results.map((task, i) => {
                console.log("-> " + task.get("name"));
                return (<li key={i}>
                        {task.get("name")}
                    </li>
                );
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my render method, I'm calling this `renderListItems` method in 'render'

```
 render() {
    return (

            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.renderListItems()}
                </ul>
            </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Add return before results.map

Comment: added, didn't work

Comment: I believe renderListItems should return out ...try adding to that

Comment: `renderListItems` never actually returns anything to the `render` function

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: your `renderListItems()` method does not return anything at all.

Data fetching logic should NOT be part of the render method. You should extract all that logic to perhaps the lifecycle method componentDidMount() if you wish the data to be fetched after the component is mounted. Otherwise, you will have to make a button that when clicking will call a function to fetch data.

You can store the data in the component state and simply do the following for renderListItems():

```
renderListItems() {
  return this.state.results.map((task, i) => {
      console.log("-> " + task.get("name"));
      return (<li key={i}>
              {task.get("name")}
          </li>
      );
  });
}
```

As a side note, I would not use the array index for the key prop of each `<li>`. You can google about that. Instead, I would use some unique identifier, like the `task.id` (if there is one).